# atlassian-python-api - How to trigger pipeline using pattern?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud, atlassian-python-api

In my project I host at the bitbucket I have such `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: "Test and build"
        ...do something
    - step:
        name: "Deploy to test"
        ...do something
  tags:
    release-*:
    - step:
        name: "Test and build"
        ...do something
    - step:
        name: "Deploy to test"
        ...do something
    - step:
        name: "Deploy to prod"
        ...do something else
```

I would like to trigger the pipeline with the `release-*` steps using the `atlassian-python-api`. However each time I try to do this I get `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url`. My code looks like this:

```
  bitbucket = Cloud(url=URL, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, cloud=True)
    r = bitbucket.workspaces.get(WORKSPACE).projects.get(PROJECT).repositories.get(REPOSITORY)
    t = r.pipelines.trigger(
        branch="master",
        commit="<COMMIT HASH>",
        pattern="release-*"
    )
```

How to change the pattern so I'll be able to run the `release-*` pipeline ?